# how to use limit and offset clause in JdbcPagingItemReader in spring batch?

Tags: parallel-processing, spring-batch

The table has more than 200 million records, but i need to restrict the select top 5 million records. I have tried with jdbcCursorItemReader which is taking around 2-3 hrs to select and write it to the csv file using single step by chunk processing, So i choose to go with parallel processing that spring is batch offering.
i,e by having taskExecutor and JdbcPagingItemReader making each 5 individual files of million each but the problem is i am not able to specify the limit and offset clause in query parameters.   please help me on this.  Approach better than this too is appreciated.

```html
<bean id="itemReader" class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcPagingItemReader" scope="step">
  <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
  <property name="rowMapper">
    <bean class="MyRowMapper" />
  </property>
  <property name="queryProvider">
    <bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.support.SqlPagingQueryProviderFactoryBean">
      <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
      <property name="sortKeys">
        <map>
                    <entry key="esmeaddr" value="ASCENDING"/>
                </map>
      </property>
      <property name="selectClause" value="elect cust_send,dest,msg,stime,dtime,dn_status,mid,rp,operator,circle,cust_mid,first_attempt,second_attempt,third_attempt,fourth_attempt,fifth_attempt,term_operator,term_circle,bindata,reason,tag1,tag2,tag3,tag4,tag5"
      />
      <property name="fromClause" value="FROM bill_log " />
      <property name="whereClause" value="where esmeaddr = '70897600000000' and country='India' and apptype='SMS' Limit 0,1000000" />
    </bean>
  </property>
  <property name="pageSize" value="1000000" />
  <property name="parameterValues">
    <map>
            <entry key="param1" value="#{jobExecutionContext[param1]}" />
            <entry key="param2" value="#{jobExecutionContext[param2]}" />
        </map>
  </property>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't use a SQL LIMIT clause within that reader since that's what the reader itself will do.  Instead, Spring Batch has the functionality built into the `JdbcPagingItemReader`.  To set the max number of items to process, you can configure the reader with `JdbcPagingItemReader#setMaxItemCount(5000000)` and if there is an offset, you would set the `JdbcPagingItemReader#setCurrentItemCount(offset)`.  That being said, the offset will be overriden on a restart with any value it finds in the `ExecutionContext`.  You can read more about this in the javadoc here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/item/database/JdbcPagingItemReader.html

Comment: Thank you very much @MichealMinella. the link provided helped me a lot.